# How do you make a slider display information as you slide in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, svg

At the moment, all I really have is the code below, and some SVG's I build with a D3 javascript library. I'd like to be able to display the index number as I'm sliding (before I end the click) so that I do not have to guess (notice there are 10,000 possible indices). I hope later that I can pair this with a JSON file and get actual values instead of numbers, but for now, I'd really know to know how to simply display them. (not on the console, but right above/below my slider)

```
    <input type = "range" min="0" max="10000" value="0" step="1" id="slider"/>
```

```
    var ARR_INDEX = 0;
    $("#slider").on("change",function(){
        ARR_INDEX = $(this).val();
        updateData(ARR_INDEX);
        console.log(ARR_INDEX);
    });
```

Comment: I did this in this example. Let me know if you can't see it, but the source should be accessible as well. https://secure.scheduleinterpreter.com/bestinterpreters/wip/dashboard/ada/grouping/slider.003.html I think this is one of the official examples somewhere on Bostock's website. Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the onmousemove and onmouseup events as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Slider value</title>
</head>

<body>

<input onmousemove=sliderChanged() onmouseup=setSliderValue() style='width:500px;' type = "range" min="0" max="10000" value="0" step="1" id="slider"/>
<span id=sliderValueSpan></span>

</body>
 <script>
 function sliderChanged()
 {
   sliderValueSpan.innerHTML=slider.value
 }
 function setSliderValue()
 {
  slider.value=sliderValueSpan.innerHTML
 }


 </script>
</html>
```